# How to update outgoing mail address in Canvas LMS with Ruby on Rails 2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I’m using Ruby on Rails 2.3.14 to develop Canvas LMS in development and staging environments before using Capistrano to deploy updates to staging from Git repo and have confirmed all updated code deploys successfully.

During the initial setup on development I configured the **outgoing_mail.yml** to use “**donotreply@mysite.com**” temporarily until I created the email address I planned to used for production according to the production installation guide https://github.com/instructure/canvas-lms/wiki/Production-Start

**Original settings:**

```
development:
  address: "smtp.mysite.com"
  port: "25"
  domain: "mysite.com"
  outgoing_address: "donotreply@mysite.com"
  default_name: "My Canvas Site"
```

I have update the outgoing_address in outgoing_mail.yml to use a different email (support@mysite.com) but the original address still appears in the “From” field on the email (donotreply@mysite.com)

**Updated settings:**

```
development:
  address: "smtp.mysite.com"
  port: "25"
  domain: "mysite.com"
  outgoing_address: "support@mysite.com"
  default_name: "My Canvas Site"

staging:
  address: "smtp.mysite.com"
  port: "25"
  domain: "mysite.com"
  outgoing_address: "support@mysite.com"
  default_name: "My Canvas Site"
```

In addition, emails sent by Canvas on staging environment default to the following:

```
Instructure Canvas notifications@unknowndomain.example.com
```

I have confirmed that both environments have the same outgoing_mail.yml settings, even checked ActionMailer::Base.settings with irb console.

I have searched the database for any table that may store configuration settings for the Canvas application but found none.

Are initial configuration settings stored somewhere outside the database or application code that Canvas LMS can be referencing?

Are there additional rake tasks that need to be run after updating configuration files for Rails applications?

How can Canvas be using old configuration settings to send emails after outging_mail.yml has been updated?